# Android WorkManager SQLiteException: no such table: worktag (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am Using workmanager library for uploading my answers to server,for the first time when i install application to device when i click on the button to upload my answer app gets crashed with error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: WorkManager-WorkManagerTaskExecutor-thread-0   
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: worktag (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while 
 compiling: SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM worktag WHERE work_spec_id=?
```

when i reopen the app then it works fine.

creating custom workmanager initializer is also not working.I am using

```
 implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
```

but is have also tried using androidx latest work manager depedency its still not working

```
 implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0"
```

Comment: As the error says: "SQLiteException: no such table: worktag" 
This is not an Issue with workmanager but with your sql querry

Comment: this is the issue of workmanager  because its failing to create the table even after its initialized.Please see the package of SQLiteException its from android.database
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: WorkManager-WorkManagerTaskExecutor-thread-0

Comment: Before creating table in Database, you try to access it. That's the issue.

Comment: creating of workmanager database table is library part we cant do anything about it .I create the work request then enqueue it to workmanager. First time it give this error after that it works smoothly.

Comment: any solutions.. please recommend me.

Comment: Hi @AdarshBinjola, were you able to find a solution for this?